# Révélatoire / révélateur

Tags: adjectifs, définition

Quelle est la différence entre *révélatoire* et *révélateur* ?

Antidote donne la même définition pour les deux mots.

> **révélateur** : Qui révèle quelque chose. *Un geste révélateur de malaise.
> Un signe révélateur d’une trop grande confiance en ses moyens*.
>
> **révélatoire** : (SOUTENU) Qui révèle quelque chose. *Lapsus révélatoire.
> Faits révélatoires.*

Je ne trouve pas une définition plus précise sur Internet.

Donc, *révélatoire* a la même signification que *révélateur* en étant plus soutenu ? Une réponse ou une remarque peut être révélatrice ou révélatoire, et le sens restera le même ?

Answer (score 3):

*Révélatoire* est tellement rare que l'utiliser risque fort de faire penser qu'on s'est trompé de mot. Je n'ai jamais entendu que ***lapsus révélateur***.

S'il fallait trouver une différence de sens, je dirais que ***révélateur*** tend à être plus concret, la révélation a probablement déjà eu lieu alors que ***révélatoire*** est réservé à des textes plus abstraits, mystiques.